# regular expression to find unreadable characters in the file name

Tags: regex, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle12c

I have a huge file containing 4.1 million records and need to find these - `Clock Accuracy â€“ SM111.ppt` kind of files which have unreadable characters. Another such exampole is - `241395 - AnsprÃ¼che.doc`

How to match this using regular expression. I am using oracle 12c database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks a lot like a problem with the character encoding of your file. The file appears to be UTF-8-encoded: `Ã¼` stands for `ü`, which makes `Ansprüche.doc` make sense. `â€“` encodes the N-dash (`–`) and so on.

So you need to open the file using UTF-8 as its encoding, then the correct characters should appear (unless the file is corrupted by using several encodings at once).

Comment: I agree. But the requirement is to check all the files using regular expression in the Oracle DB. I have dumped this whole file into the DB and would like to perform some operation on this.